# ews mail details showing the error "Id is malformed"

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

When I'm trying to get office 365 mail details for a mail id using Exchange web Service there are an error showing "Id is malformed" to me.
I have written the following code to get the mail details-

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(Ownerusername, OwnerPassword);

service.AutodiscoverUrl(Ownerusername, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
EmailMessage mail = EmailMessage.Bind(service, mailID, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```

The last line showing me the error `"Id is malformed"`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did the mailID come from ? the error is telling you its not a valid EWSId (which it probably isn't).

Comment: The "mailID" is a valid office 365 mail id which showing on a asp.net gridview. Clicking on the grid row I could retrieve the mailID.

Comment: Okay but that Id isn't valid in EWS (the error is telling you this much) you need to use an EWSId that you get from the FindItem operation. You maybe able to covert the Id you have but your answer doesn't indicate what Id it is (eg there is no such thing as an office365 mailid) You might want to post the code where you are obtaining the MailId which will make more sense to anybody looking at your question.

Comment: I'm using the following code to populate the record for gridview: FindItemsResults<Item> fiitems = null;
fiitems = service.FindItems(folderId, itemView); foreach (Item item in fiitems) string mailID = item.id; }  The "Id is malformed" error is not showing for all user's mail it's showing for some particular user mailID only. Is there any mailid conversion issue? An example of a mailid which caused an error is "AAMkADQwMDQ5MGM1LWY5N2EtNDZiNi04NTcyLTc5ZGZmNmE3MzRkZgBGAAAAAACGC5Y0IFP4lllkVoYCy6xvBwA0Pv I6TFRRp1G RwASpMNAAAAAAEMAAA0Pv I6TFRRp1G RwASpMNAAAddbN9AAA=" 
                {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Request.QueryString["mailID"] value was not formatted correctly. Thanks for your valuable opinion.